# Expect append to list

Tags: list, expect

How can I append $interface to the list $interfaces?

```
expect -re "(.*) ago, via (.*)\r" { lappend interfaces $expect_out(2,string) }

foreach interface $interfaces {
        puts "$interface"
}
```

The value 2 into regular expression exists, but the my code returns:

```
can't read "interfaces": no such variable
    while executing
"foreach interface $interfaces {
```

Answer (score 1):

1. are you sure that pattern matches? Run your program with `expect -d` to be sure
2. protect yourself from the error:

   ```
   if {[info exists interfaces]} {
       foreach intf $interfaces {puts $intf}
   } else {
       puts "error: no interfaces found"
   }
   ```

---

As you want to extract many interfaces, you need some form of looping. Try this:

```
send "command to produce interface names\r"
expect {
    -re {via ([^\r]+)} {
        lappend interfaces $expect_out(1,string)
        exp_continue
    }
    "prompt> "
}
```

Alter "prompt> " to whatever you need to expect when you're done grabbing interface names.

Comment: Ok. And if I've more lines can I do something like this?

        while...{
                expect -re "(.*) ago, via (.*)\r" { lappend interfaces $expect_out(2,string) }
        }


I would like grab more lines (more $interfaces).
Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not able to find an example. I'd like parsing more lines and put the matched values into a list to show using a foreach. Seems very complicated with tcl :)

Comment: I'm very appreciating your help.

With the latest mofidy the code returns: "can't read "interfaces": no such variable"

The buffer produced by the command is:
 * 1.1.1.1, from 2.2.2.2, 00:00:00 ago, via Int1
   3.3.3.3, from 4.4.4.4, 00:00:00 ago, via Int2

and individually is parsed correctly by the regular expression :(

Comment: Ok ok! expect -d is the salvation! :)
The output of the command is all in a single row.
Into a expect -re block can I set and send? Two operation into a single block? Thank you